# Communication microservice - Email verification Link

Tags: authentication, domain-driven-design, microservices, bounded-contexts

I have 2 microservices Identity & Communication. When user signs up, I want to send him an activation link to his email. Activation link is generated on Identity side, how can I pass it to Communication Microservice to send an email? or Communication microservice shoudn't exist as a separate microservice, but each microservice can use IEmailSender utility to send emails?

Comment: DomainEvents dispatched through messaging infrastructure are often used for cross-bounded-context integration.  Identity fires the UserSignedUp event and the event gets consumed by the Communication BC. This couples your Communication BC to events from the Identity context though which you may not want. An alternative could be to dispatch the UserSignedUp event locally with a handler that calls upon the Comms BC through an anti-corruption layer service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Communication Bounded Context is wrong for my system. Its just a technical Help SErvice which every Bounded Context should have in Order to fulfill its business capabilities. For example Identity in order to Activate Account needs this infrastructural posibility. Removed communication BC, and sending emails directly from Identity.

Answer (score 0):

I typically have an endpoint that handles e-mails.  I use my [Shuttle.Esb](http://shuttle.github.io/shuttle-esb/) open-source service bus to facilitate messaging but any service bus will do or you may opt for coding the messaging directly using something like RabbitMQ.

Integration between endpoints is handled by an orchestration endpoint for the bounded context in question.  This orchestration layer would send a `SendEMailCommand` to the e-mail endpoint and then receive confirmation once the e-mail has been successfully dispatched.  In this way there is a single point that handles e-mails.

When you have every bounded context access something like an `IEMailGateway` it means that you may need to do a bit more legwork in terms of getting the e-mail going since you need access to the relevant mail server and that may mean dealing with firewalls, ports,  security